# переключение между 2 макетами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

В приложении нужно реализовать смену лайаутов при нажатии на кнопку, которые вынесены в отдельные классы. У меня это получилось сделать, но меня смущает, что при каждом нажатии приходится создавать новый экземпляр класса. 
Содержимое классов, наследующих QVBoxLayout, менять не надо, т.к. в том коде, на котором построен пример, они, помимо большего числа виджетов, содержат минимум 2 лайаута.
Пример: https://pastebin.com/99j8mMx1

Comment: Как насчет [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html)?

Comment: Он бы подошел, если можно было бы добавлять в него макеты.

Comment: Что за макеты? В Qt нет такого термина. Или вы про layout (компоновщики) говорили? Тогда, делать так: создавать QWidget под каждый layout, помещать на QStackedWidget те виджеты с layout

Comment: Да, я про layout'ы говорил. А нормально, что компоновщик с виджетами надо добавить в объект QWidget чтобы его добавить QStackedWidget?

Comment: Конечно, не вижу в этом никакой проблемы. Правильно заводить отдельные классы виджетов с установленными на них компоновщиками с другими виджетами, например для виджета логина/пароль и основного окна